# Can't push commit to GitHub in IntelliJ: fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, repository

I'm getting the following error when I try to commit and push to my GitHub repo.

```
Push failed
        RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
        the remote end hung up unexpectedly
        Total 1116 (delta 148), reused 45 (delta 0)
        the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And following in the Git Console (Read-Only):

```
Total 1116 (delta 148), reused 45 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So from what I have been able to find out so far it is because the commit is too big. That's realistic because I added about 0.7 GB of test resources to my local files and IntelliJ added them to the repo.

I have very little experience with GitHub and I don't know how to get out of this ?

I tried to fix it by deleting the resource folder from the repo (on Github.com) and adding it to gitignore file than updating the project in IntelliJ. This first seemed to work but after I edited a few lines of code and tried to commit and push the same error came.

So what to do now? I've found something about setting the buffer size (?) but I don't know how to do it in IntelliJ (after all the git console in IntelliJ is read-only).

Comment: Are you committing complied/built code or binaries?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's a very good question. If I go on Github.com I can view the source code as text. Maybe that gives you a hint else where can I look that up ?

Answer (score 1):

So a solution is the following:

-Update all the files you want to keep to github (via website for exmaple)
-Remove your project from IntelliJ (or at least the .git folder)
-Check into your repo

Not nice but it works.

Comment: Did you delete the `.git` folder?

Answer (score -1):

changing the internet connection worked for me. the error was:

RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) 6970 bytes of body are still expected fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet early EOF fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output